# Where do I mount a drive so that both Plex and FileBot can access it?

Tags: permissions, mount, plex

I have 2 drives in my machine that I want to use with Ubuntu. Ubuntu lives on a 256GB SSD and I would like to use a 4TB HHD for media storage and backups. I use Filebot to rename media and Plex as a media server. I initially allowed Ubuntu to decide where to mount the HHD. Filebot could save to the drive but Plex couldn't see it. I moved it's mount point to `/mnt/<drive_name>` using the Disks utility. Now Plex can see it but Filebot says it's in a read-only file system. I tried to `sudo chmod -R a+rwx /mnt/<drive_name>` but Filebot still throws the same error. Where should I mount the drive so that both Plex and Filebot can access it?

I would also like Transmission to be able to dl to that drive also. I haven't tried it yet, but hopefully, any mount point accessable to both other programs will be accessible to Transmission as well.

Ubuntu 17.10 if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the mount point to `/home/<drive_name>` and that seems to be working. I can access the files with Filebot, Transmission, and Plex.